# Why does PriorityQueue not work properly?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Here is my code:

```
public static List<int[]> getSkyline(int[][] buildings) {
    List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<>();

    PriorityQueue<int[]> heights = new PriorityQueue<>(buildings.length * 2, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            if (o1[0] == o2[0]) {
                return o1[1] - o2[1];
            } else {
                return o1[0] - o2[0];
            }
        }
    });

    for (int[] h : buildings) {
        heights.add(new int[]{h[0], -h[2]});
        heights.add(new int[]{h[1], h[2]});
    }


    for (int[] height : heights) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(height));
    }

    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getSkyline(new int[][]{{0, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 3}});

}
```

In my idea, as the input is `new int[][]{{0, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 3}}`, the output should be `[0, -3][2, -3][2, 3][5, 3]`, but actually it shows `[0, -3][2, 3][2, -3][5, 3]`. Could anybody tell me what is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that`PriorityQueue<T>` does not order elements on iteration:

The documentation for `public Iterator<E> iterator()` states that the method

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

To get the ordering that you expect you need to remove elements from the priority queue one by one, and print them:

```
while (heights.size() != 0) {
    int[] height = heights.poll();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(height));
}
```

This change produces the following output:

```
[0, -3]
[2, -3]
[2, 3]
[5, 3]
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RCcY8g)